# Programmatically Assign Customer Group for Selected Category Product Order

Tags: product, customer-group

I want to assign a customer group for the customers, who have placed the order from selected category or particular products.

I have a category name `grouper`. In this category, I have some products with SKU names `x1`,`x2` and `x3`.

I also have the Customer Group named same as product of this category. ie  `x1`,`x2` and `x3` and these products can only be purchased alone.

So when I purchased or place order `x1` then the customer group for this customer should assign as `x1`. When the order is success the group should assign.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a observer for checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and add the below code, and its get works well.

```
    $mem_catid = 8; //CATEGORY ID products to filter
    $_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
    $order->load($lastOrderId);
    $allitems = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach($allitems as $item)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if (in_array($mem_catid, $categoryIds)) {
            $mem_group_id = $item->getSku();  // $item->getSku() is customer group name
            $customer_detail = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customer_detail->setGroupId($mem_group_id);
            $customer_detail->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't make it clear at what point you want to do this in the process, but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
// array of special products
$products = array(1,2,3,4);
// flag
$changeGroup = false;
// group to move customer to
$groupId = 1234;

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')-loadByEmail($email);

$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
->addAttributeToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED));

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
    if (in_array($orderItem->getProductId(), $products)) {
        $changeGroup = true;
    }
}

if ($changeGroup == true) {
    $customer->setGroupId($groupId);
    $customer->save();
}
```

Comment: Douglas, thanks for your answer. when the order is success the group should assign.